# Pass value of Input to handleMethod

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Task is to pass each character entered to `handleExchange` method. In this method, processing of entered values ​​will occur.

How do I pass an input tag to argument of `handleExchange` method?

```js
function App() {

    function handleExchange(value) {
      console.log(value)
    }

    return (
      <input className = "input-r" placeholder = "Type here" />
    )


}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I tried to do this:

```js
function App() {
  function handleExchange(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input className="input-r" placeholder="Type here" onKeyPress={handleExchange(this.value)} /> 
      {/*or*/}
      {/* onKeyPress={handleExchange(event) */}
    </div>
  )

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is well described [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). I suggest you read it through first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `onChange` event and get value from `event.target`.

There you have example:

```js
function App() {
  function handleExchange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input className="input-r" placeholder="Type here" onChange={handleExchange} /> 
      {/*or*/}
      {/* onKeyPress={handleExchange(event) */}
    </div>
  )

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an [`onChange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange) handler to the the `input` element. Note: the handler passes the `event` so you need to grab the value from the event target. Here I've used [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
function App() {

    function handleExchange(e) {
      const { target: { value } } = e;
      console.log(value)
    }

    return (
      <input
        className="input-r"
        placeholder="Type here"
        onChange={handleExchange}
      />
    );

}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```